# In a custom Puppet ruby function, is it possible to store persistent data per catalog run?

Tags: ruby, puppet

With Puppet, in a custom ruby function is it possible to cache a value for a single catalog run?

I have this function:

```
Puppet::Functions.create_function(:myFunction) do

    def myFunction( *arguments )
        data = call_function( 'lookup', [ 'myHieraKey', nil, nil, {} ] )
        data.length()
    end

end
```

The function is called multiple times and would be more optimal if each invocation didn't query hiera.

I can't seem to find any hints as to how to do this. A quick and dirty way could be to define a unique class variable, however this pollutes one of the Puppet classes.

> @@mymodule_myfunction_myvariable = {}

Is there a "proper" way?

Comment: Indeed a class variable would be analogous to a static variable in a low level language, but would indeed also "pollute" your code. However, your code also implies the Hiera lookup will be identical during each function invocation, so why not refactor the `lookup` to be an argument passed into the function instead? Then the `lookup` will only occur once each catalog compilation.

Comment: Thanks @MattSchuchard - while possible I'd have to wrap this ruby function with a puppet define that has access to a puppet class variable. I was hoping for something "neater".

Comment: There is no per-catalog-(compilation / run) scoping at the plugin level.  If that's the scope you need then it must be driven from the Puppet DSL level, where such scoping is implicit, at least for classes and nodes.